# How do I save sockets in a hash and loop over them from another thread?

Tags: perl, sockets, multithreading

I am working on a mulithreaded TCP server. In the main thread, I listen on a socket and create a new thread for new incoming connections. I want to save all incoming connections in a hash so that I can access them from yet another thread.

From the monitor thread, I can not read any newly added connections. It seems a new clients hash is created when creating the monitor thread.

How do i keep list of all sockets and loop them from my monitor thread?

Current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use IO::Socket;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

# init
my $clients = {};
my $queue = Thread::Queue->new;

# thread that monitors
threads->create("monitor");

# create the listen socket
my $listenSocket = IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort  => 12345,
                                      Listen   => 10,
                                      Proto   => 'tcp',
                                      Reuse   => 1);

# make sure we are bound to the port
die "Cant't create a listening socket: $@" unless $listenSocket;

print "Server ready. Waiting for connections on 34567 ... \n";

# wait for connections at the accept call
while (my $connection = $listenSocket->accept) {
    # set client socket to non blocking
    my $nonblocking = 1;
    ioctl($connection, 0x8004667e, \\$nonblocking);

    # autoflush
    $connection->autoflush(1);

    # debug
    print "Accepted new connection\n";

    # add to list
    $clients->{time()} = $connection;

    # start new thread and listen on the socket
    threads->create("readData", $connection);
}

sub readData {
     # socket parameter
     my ($client) = @_;

     # read client
     while (<$client>) {
      # remove newline
      chomp $_;

  # add to queue
      $queue->enqueue($_);
     }

     close $client;
}

sub monitor {
    # endless loop
    while (1) {

        # loop while there is something in the queue
        while ($queue->pending) {

            # get data from a queue
            my $data = $queue->dequeue;

            # loop all sockets
            while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%$clients) ) {

               # send to socket
               print $value "$data\n";

            }
        }

        # wait 0,25 seconds
        select(undef, undef, undef, 0.25);
    }
}

close $listenSocket;
```

Comment: Tip, possibly useful to you, maybe not: Ever seen a module named `IO::Multiplex`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to share `$clients` via `share` from [`threads::shared`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html):

```
my $clients = &share({});
```

The old-fashioned syntax is due to a documented issue with Perl’s prototypes. If you have [at least Perl 5.8.9](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl589delta.html), use the nicer

```
my $clients = shared_clone({});
```

instead.

You also want to protect `$clients` with a lock, *e.g.*,

```
my $clients_lock : shared;
{
  lock $clients_lock;
  $clients->{time()} = fileno $connection;
}
```

Finally, because `IO::Socket::INET` instances are Perl typeglobs, you can’t share them, so instead add their socket descriptors (from [`fileno`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html)) to `$clients` and then `fdopen` the socket when necessary with

```
open my $fh, ">&=", $sockdesc or warn ...
```

The program below repeats inbound data to the other connected sockets:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use IO::Socket;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

# init
my $clients = &share({});
my $clients_lock : shared;

my $queue = Thread::Queue->new;

# thread that monitors
threads->create("monitor");

# create the listen socket
my $port = 12345;
my $listenSocket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
  LocalPort  => $port,
  Listen     => 10,
  Proto      => 'tcp',
  Reuse      => 1
);

# make sure we are bound to the port
die "Can't create a listening socket: $@" unless $listenSocket;

print "Server ready. Waiting for connections on $port ... \n";

# wait for connections at the accept call
while (my $connection = $listenSocket->accept) {
  # set client socket to non blocking
  my $nonblocking = 1;
  ioctl($connection, 0x8004667e, \\$nonblocking);

  # autoflush
  $connection->autoflush(1);

  # debug
  print "Accepted new connection\n";

  # add to list
  {
    lock $clients_lock;
    $clients->{time()} = fileno $connection;
  }

  # start new thread and listen on the socket
  threads->create("readData", $connection);
}

sub readData {
  # socket parameter
  my ($client) = @_;

  # read client
  while (<$client>) {
    chomp;
    $queue->enqueue($_);
  }

  close $client;
}

sub monitor {
  # endless loop
  while (1) {
    # loop while there is something in the queue
    while ($queue->pending) {
      # get data from a queue
      my $data = $queue->dequeue;

      # loop all sockets
      {
        lock $clients_lock;
        while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%$clients) ) {
          # send to socket
          if (open my $fh, ">&=", $value) {
            print $fh "$data\n";
          }
          else {
            warn "$0: fdopen $value: $!";
          }
        }
      }
    }

    # wait 0,25 seconds
    select(undef, undef, undef, 0.25);
  }
}

close $listenSocket;
```

Comment: upvoted, Thanks for mentioning fileno function to convert the socket connection to file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have too much experience using threads in Perl, but I think you just want to share your client list:

```
    use threads::shared;
    my $clients : shared = {};
```

---

**Update:**

Perl complains about:

```
my $hash : shared = {};
```

but it seems to be ok with:

```
my $hash = {};
share($hash);
```

Also, this code:

```
my $hash = { key1 => "value1" };
share($hash);
```

seems to clear the hashtable, but

```
my $hash = {};
share($hash);
$hash->{key1} = "value1";
```

works like I'd expect.

Comment: This doesnt work, 2nd line gives an error "Invalid value for shared scalar at test.pl line 9."